# Проблема с маской ввода в Access

Tags: ms-access

В поле таблицы формата DataTime с маской короткой даты (ДД.ММ.ГГГГ) сохраняется дата, например 30.12.2023.
Поиск записи с этой датой через SQL выглядит так:

```
WHERE
MyData = #30/12/2023#
```

Через форму хочу сделать поле для поиска по дате, но дата обязательно должна быть в формате ММ/ДД/ГГГГ.
Из этого 2 вопроса: Можно ли как то сделать чтобы вводился сначала день потом месяц (как в формате короткой даты) и как сделать маску ввода для поля на форме с разделителем `/`. Когда я пишу `00/00/0000;0;_` при нажатии Enter сам Access автоматически заменяет все на `00.00.0000;0;_`. Но именно запись через `.` вместо `/` вызывает в последствии ошибку при выполнении запроса. Работаю в версии Access 2007

Comment: Вводить пользователь должен дату  в формате, в котором принято вводить. Access поймет 31.12.2023  и 31/12/23. Для фильтра используйте форматирование ``WHERE MyData =" & "#" & Format(dt, "mm\/dd\/yyyy") & "#"``